# Initialize Octave process inside C++ program and write commands to the standered input

Tags: c++, octave

I'm working on a C++ project and I need to initialize a octave process inside my program and write octave commands into octave standard input and get results from octave standard output and standard error.

I searched and found that octave forge engine package do that job. But I couldn't find how to use that package. I just want to execute simple command such as 5+5 and get the answer.

Is there any way of doing this using octave [engine](http://octave.sourceforge.net/engine/index.html) package or using any other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I created a [QProcess](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qprocess.html) using Qt.

```
QStringList arguments;
    arguments << "--persist"; //set arguments of the octave process. --persist:Go interactive after
    octave.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels); //set process channel
    octave.start("/usr/bin/octave", arguments);//If octave has installed into any other directory this should be changed.
```

After that I was able to write to the standered input of the octave process.

```
if(octave.state()==QProcess::Starting){
        octave.waitForStarted();
        //TODO:should set a timeout and if timeout happens set a error report.
        processWrite(command);
    }
    else if(octave.state()==QProcess::Running){
        //TODO write Code
        octave.waitForReadyRead(1000);//wait until Standered output ready
        if(command.isEmpty()){
            return;
        }
        else{
            command+="\n";
            octave.write(command.toUtf8());
        }
    }
    else{
        //TODO: Error reporting
    }
```